# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

http://localhost:8080/asset/js/boostrap.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

In my folder asset/js/

I´ve the file boostrap.min.js

What´s the problem?

Comment: It's looking in the public folder.  Where is your asset folder at?

Comment: yes my asset is in the public folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons you get a file not found exception. The most popular is the file permissions. If you are on UNIX try
 `chmod -R 777` 
in the folder  that contains bootstrap.min.js. If this doesn't works you have to review the server conf files or the .htaccess files.

If you want a "just works solution" include the bootstrap from a cdn.

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
```

If none of the above works for you please post your .htaccess contents from the directory which bootstrap is located.

Comment: Definitely don't recommend 777 permissions.  Are you aware of the security implications of such permissions?  Not sure how you can recommend that if you are.

Comment: This is just for test reasons.  He is on localhost. If you plan to make your home or work computer as a production webserver , I also do not recommend 777 permissions. This is just an easy way to make sure you can  access a file.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't notice the local host bit

Comment: I suspect you are not using xampp (8080 port) but the php server. The problem is that your webserver is not reaching the bootstrap.min.js. Did you try the cdn to see if it working?

Comment: So we can tell that you browser can't reach the file. Laravel and other frameworks (like Symfony to wich Laravel is based on) have many .htaccess files that accomplish different things. How did you launch your webserver. I suspect that if you try to start a php webserver instance on the asset/js directory you can access the localhost:8000/bootstrap.min.js file.
You do this by going to the bootstrap.min.js directory and type in cmd:
php -S localhost:8000

Comment: A permission problem cannot raise a 404 error in the browser's log. If it was a permission issue, it would have been a 403 permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('asset/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

try `{{ HTML::script('asset/js/boostrap.min.js') }}`
and put the boostrap.min.js into the public/asset/js folder

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with simply referencing `app.css` and this worked:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="{{('css/app.css')}}"
```

I'm not exactly sure why the `{{}}` around `css/app.css` works. I didn't have the braces before and got `error 404`. Can someone explain why the braces resolve the `not found 404 error`?