# How to add jQuery in Laravel project

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel framework.
I want to use jQuery in web application built using Laravel framework.

But don't know how to link to **jQuery library** in Laravel project.

Comment: just add the jquery link manually in your blade template head or you can use elixer/gulp..though I think you need to watch https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals which will guide you better in your laravel journey .

Comment: thank you, i am still watching these video, though I've got little understanding ...

Comment: same here when I was starting..the secret is never give up on learning..just keep repeating the videos as you needed :-) good luck.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can use online library

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or else download library and add  css in css folder and jquery in js folder.both folder you keep in laravel public folder then you can link like below

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')}}">
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

or else

```php
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/functions.js') }}
```

Comment: I have a write     <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script> in the page, and I also have jquery.min.js in js folder in public folder. Still i have got error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (16:17:19:682 | error, network)
  at public/js/jquery-1.11.3.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (16:17:19:690 | error, javascript)
    at (anonymous function) (http://localhost:8000/jquery/index:7:9)
Debugging session with browser was closed.

Comment: try using online library then what hapeen ?

Comment: better ypu use online library instead of loading from your resource folder

Comment: also you can look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614890/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found

Comment: even i get error some time.so i am using online library

Comment: This solution works, but, isn't there a way to add jquery using npm?

Answer (score 23):

To add jquery to laravel you first have to add the Scaffolded javascript file, app.js to your top layout.

This can easily be done adding this tag.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

There are two main procesess depending on the version but at the **end** of both you will have to execute:

```
npm run dev
```

That adds all the dependencies to the app.js file. But if you want this process to be done automatically for you, you can also run:

```
npm run watch
```

Wich will keep watching for changes and add them.

#### Laravel 5.*

jQuery is already included in this version of laravel as a dev dependency.

You just have to run:

```
npm install
```

This first command will install the dependencies. jquery will be added.

#### Laravel 6.* , 7.* and 8.*

jQuery has been taken out of laravel that means you need to import it manually like so.

```
npm i jquery
```

Then add it to the bootstrap.js file in **resources/js/bootstrap.js**
You may notice that axios and lodash are imported there as well so in the same way we can import jquery.

Just add wherever you want there:

```
//In resources/js/bootstrap.js
window.$ = require('jquery');
```

If you follow this process in the 5.* version it won't affect laravel but it will install a more updated version of jquery.

Comment: This does not work for laravel 6 you need to download the jquery library and add it to your public folder

Comment: @Jiren Your way also works. The difference with mine is that am using laravel mix to add this to the app.js file. The advantage of my way is scripts management and laravel mix uglifies your code using webpack. Also you may wish to import specific functionalities of jquery instead of the complete library, you can do that my way. If you are commenting because it didn't worked for you remember you need to execute npm run dev or npm run watch. This is the way i use.

Comment: @Jiren I just want to say that this is standard good practice to add external javascript libraries to laravel. You just have to check the  resources/js/bootstrap.js file and you'll notice that lodash and axios are imported this way.

Comment: This was helpful. For whatever reason, I imported a library with npm whose .js file already included jquery, but it refused to work. Manually pulling jquery and then including that line in bootstrap.js resolved this. Laravel is great in many ways, but the learning curve for this type of task is rather high. I went from wanting to just learning Laravel to being forced to also learn about npm, mixins, etc, because Laravel seems to be reliant on it.

Comment: please make sure to remove "defer" keyword from the <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

Comment: it's not working in Laravel 8. is there any other solution?

Comment: @Amit did you run npm run watch or npm run dev first?

Comment: @jogarcia, yes. I run npm run dev after i install jquery using npm i jquery.

Comment: @jogarcia, I have also tried noConflict and jquery instead of $. In the console, it says '$ is not a function'

Comment: @Amit Share me your project's link on github

Comment: @jogarcia, below is the url to package.json of my application.   https://github.com/amitleuva1987/employee-management/blob/main/package.json and below is the url of my blade file where i have used jquery https://github.com/amitleuva1987/employee-management/blob/main/resources/views/company/index.blade.php    , please note, things are working because i have added jquery cdn url. if i remove cdn url, jquery will not work.

Comment: @Amit mmm, I cloned it and it's working correctly. Your problem isn't jquery. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @jogarcia, it's working because, I have used Jquery 'CDN url'. If I would remove cdn url from the 'views/company/index.blade.php', It won't work.  What I am trying to do is have jquery scaffolded while i run 'npm run dev'. I don't want a separate cdn url to make jquery run.  Btw, thanks for the time that you are giving to resolve this problem.

Comment: @jogarcia, I get it solved. I posted the same question at laravel.io and A developer gave me tracing trick to get it tracked. It worked. Below is the forum url. https://laravel.io/forum/jquery-is-not-getting-installed-with-npm-in-laravel .  Thank you very much for your time

Comment: @DavidTran That has nothing to do with Laravel per se - that's just modern web development, Laravel is simply putting you on equal footing with all the other frameworks out there. Build tools are a necessity of modern web development and once you understand how to use them, they can seriously level up your skills and improve your productivity. On top of that, believe it or not, frameworks like Laravel actually make this stuff a lot simpler - using something like Webpack on its own is a *lot* harder.

Answer (score 19):

For those using npm to install packages, you can install jquery via `npm install jquery` and then use elixir to compile jquery and your other npm packages into one file (e.g. vendor.js). Here's a sample gulpfile.js

```js
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix

    .scripts([
        'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        // list your other npm packages here
    ],
    'public/js/vendor.js', // 2nd param is the output file
    'node_modules')        // 3rd param is saying "look in /node_modules/ for these scripts"

    .scripts([
        'scripts.js'       // your custom js file located in default location: /resources/assets/js/
    ], 'public/js/app.js') // looks in default location since there's no 3rd param

    .version([             // optionally append versioning string to filename
        'js/vendor.js',    // compiled files will be in /public/build/js/
        'js/app.js'
    ]);

});
```

Answer (score 7):

In Laravel 6 you can get it like this:

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: Assigning `require('jquery')` to `window.$` _and_ `window.jQuery` instead of _just_ to `window.$` is absolutely necessary when dealing with older libraries like boostrap3. This saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

You can link libraries from [cdn](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Delivery_Network) (Content delivery network):

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Or link libraries locally, add css files in the css folder and jquery in js folder. You have to keep both folders in the laravel public folder then you can link like below:

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')}}">
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

or else

```php
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/functions.js') }}
```

If you link js files and css files locally (like in the last two examples) you need to add `js` and `css` files to the `js` and `css` folders which are in `public\js` or `public\css` not in `resources\assets`.