# how to Select and Clear all check-boxes using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, checkboxlist

I have written a code that sends email to selected people using check-box, now I have to add select all and clear all button so that all the check-boxes should get selected/dis-selected.

Here is my code:

My controller:

```
 public function display(){
        $data = Input::get('agree');
        $count = count ($data);
        $this->contact( $data );
        return view('clientinfo.display', compact('data','count'));
    }
```

My View:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')

    <h1>Welcome! Send e-mail to selected people.</h1>
    <hr>
    {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ClientsController@display','method' => 'GET'))!!}
        @foreach($clients as $client)
            {!! Form::checkbox("agree[]", $client->email, null,['id' => $client->email]) !!}
                <article>
                    {{ $client->user_name }}
                    &nbsp;
                    {{ $client->email }}

                </article>
        @endforeach
        {!! Form::submit('Send Mail',['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
    <br/>
    @include('clientinfo.newmember')
@stop
```

if i add a button in my view naming select-all and clear-all how do i relate them, to select all the members within list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes to my code and it worked using ***JavaScript***.

Here is my code:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')

    <h1>Welcome! Send e-mail to selected people.</h1>
    <hr>
    {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ClientsController@display','method' => 'GET','name'=>'f1' , 'id'=>'form_id'))!!}
    <br/>
        @foreach($clients as $client)
            <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::checkbox("agree[]", $client->email, null,['id' => $client->email], ['class' => 'questionCheckBox']), $client->email !!}
            <br/>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Send Mail',['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::button('Select All',['class' => 'btn btn-info form-control','onClick'=>'select_all("agree", "1")']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::button('Clear All',['class' => 'btn btn-danger form-control','onClick'=>'select_all("agree", "0")']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
@endsection
```

And in my master file,I have added a **JavaScript**:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var formblock;
    var forminputs;

    function prepare() {
        formblock= document.getElementById('form_id');
        forminputs = formblock.getElementsByTagName('input');
    }

    function select_all(name, value) {
        for (i = 0; i < forminputs.length; i++) {
            // regex here to check name attribute
            var regex = new RegExp(name, "i");
            if (regex.test(forminputs[i].getAttribute('name'))) {
                if (value == '1') {
                    forminputs[i].checked = true;
                } else {
                    forminputs[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("load", prepare, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onload", prepare)
    } else if (document.getElementById) {
        window.onload = prepare;
    }
</script>
```

Earlier i was doing this using Jquery, that  was not working, then i tried using **JavaScript** and it worked.
I have tried various ways to add jquery in my code which are given in answers of *stackoverflow.com*, but nothing worked in laravel. If anyone know how to use *jquery* in *laravel*, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the checkboxes a class and use jquery.
You also need a checkbox that says "select all" with an ID.

```
$(function() {
    
    $('#selectAll').click(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('.your_checkbox_class').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('.your_checkbox_class').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
    
});
```

The above code is checked by me. It works properly in new versions.
I checked it with laraval 10

Comment: @Kiwi_Juicer : Can you tell me how to use jquery in laravel?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. You should be able to just include the library according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498328/how-to-add-jquery-in-laravel-project