# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined Laravel 5.6

Tags: jquery, laravel

I've tried everything :

```
mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
});
```

I've tried `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});`

I've tried even :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

But still get the same console error knowing that I'm using **Laravel 5.6** with **Laravel Mix**

Thank you helping

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40122641/562424

Comment: It's not my problem :)

Comment: @R.Saif $(document).ready(function(){}),(jQuery);  Could you try it this way.

Comment: I'e tried already and the error will chajhe to Uncaught **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**

Answer (score 15):

If you are not using `vue` , delete everything related to `vue` from `assets/js/app.js` .

And delete "defer" from `layouts/app.blade.php`

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

to

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

This will probably work with jquery.

I don't know when using `vue`. sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the point about removing the `defer` from the script tag, never noticed it and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's an older question but if anyone else ends up reading this I'll went by answer by @kuro and found that adding defer to my own script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/path/my_script.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Like that worked for me.