# "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" but jQuery is included

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I've an error when I open webpage with jQuery code.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I've include jQuery & Bootstrap in app.js and I can't use jQuery in view.

In app.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

import 'bootstrap';
```

In layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset(mix('js/manifest.js')) }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset(mix('js/vendor.js')) }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset(mix('js/app.js')) }}"></script>
@stack('scripts')
```

In view:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert('ok');
            mediumZoom('.embedded_image img');
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

My **webpack.mix.js**:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    mix.disableNotifications();
}

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix
    .options({
        uglify: {
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true,
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .setPublicPath('public')
    .setResourceRoot('../')
    .autoload({
        jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery', 'window.$', 'jquery', 'window.jquery'],
        tether: ['window.Tether', 'Tether'],
        vue: ['window.Vue', 'Vue'],
        lodash: ['lodash', '_']
    })
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css')
    .copyDirectory('resources/assets/images', 'public/images')
    .extract([
        'highlight.js',
        'lodash',
        'popper.js',
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        'axios',
        'vue'
    ])
    .sourceMaps()
    .version();
```

I don't want to use TypeScript.

Comment: Can't you just include jQuery in your layout? `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783307/how-to-import-jquery-into-a-typescript-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add jquery in laravel project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498328/how-to-add-jquery-in-laravel-project)

Comment: It's not a duplicate issue. I don't want to use CDN, nor TypeScript.

Comment: Yes, but you want to use ES6 imports. _Did_ you try replacing `import $ from 'jquery'` with `import * as $ from jquery`?

Comment: @mbojko Yes, the same problem. Same with `require('jquery');`

Comment: Please can you show your `webpack.mix.js` as well?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes of course: https://pastebin.com/raw/0FKyetmD

Comment: @RossWilson I've updated my issue, if you want watch the `webpack.mix.js`