# Laravel 6 datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, laravel-6

how to use datatime picker in laravel 6 always i'm getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (tasks:326)
at fire (jquery.js:1037)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:1148)
at Function.ready (jquery.js:433)
at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:103)
```

Comment: Please give us help as soon, we stuck in...

Answer (score 0):

Your error has not much to do with Laravel, it's a client-side problem, you are trying to call `datepicker()` `function` of a jQuery object, but that `function` does not exist. You will need to ensure that at the point of the `function` call, the element exists as well as it complies to all criterias asked for by jQuery's datepicker. If you need further help, then provide us your structure and the relevant JS code, not just the stack trace.

Comment: this is my app.blade.php @Lajos Arpad  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script><script src="{{ asset('js/menu.js') }}" defer></script>
        <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

Comment: this is my blade <input type="text" id="datepicker"> section('scripts')
  <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
  </script>
endsection

Comment: @Ashan is it possible that you have included jquery multiple times? That's a known possible cause of this issue.

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: If jquery is included several times into your page, then the solution is to remove all its duplicates. Since you use cloudflare and it caches your stuff, you will need to empty the cache when you test

Comment: where i put jquery file proper in laravel 6

Comment: This might be interesting from that perspective: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498328/how-to-add-jquery-in-laravel-project