# Laravel + adminLTE3 jquery and other dependencies not found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, adminlte

I discovered a link to integrate adminLTE in Laravel 8 and I followed it.

Here is the [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/integrating-adminlte-3-and-laravel-8-51c1555efa60).

But when im going to use jquery's `document.ready` and `toastr`. It says `$ not defined or toastr not defined`. Im not installing jquery or `toastr` since I assume its included in adminLTE as the docs said.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: npm install
npm run dev

Comment: i already did it. @tirtakeniten

Comment: where do you call the $?

Comment: in script. @tirtakeniten

Comment: This question is answered By jogarcia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498328/how-to-add-jquery-in-laravel-project/56794159

Comment: @SallarMumtaz no. my problem is different. jquery is included already in adminLTE. I dont need to add an cdn since it can cause complications if there are multiple jquery

Answer (score 0):

> To add jquery to laravel you first have to add the Scaffolded
> javascript file, app.js
>
> This can easily be done adding this tag.

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Please see complete answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794159/14249612