# How can I define jQuery on Laravel-vite config and use on other external libraries?

Tags: jquery, laravel, vite

I want to import jQuery as EC6 to bootstra.js. and finally access to jQuery whole of the project.

bootstrap.js:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = jQuery
```

index.blade.php:

```
there is an external script that uses jQuery
```

so we have two external script:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="x.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so, after runing Vite on dev mode, I'm getting below error:

```
jQuery is not defined
```

Comment: Maybe try looking here if it’s no use sorry [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498328/how-to-add-jquery-in-laravel-project)